# Como Generar una consulta en PL ORACLE con la funcion COUNT?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero no soy experto en el tema, en esta consulta he logrado obtener los registros de la tabla  RTI_MZMPIO pero a la vez requiero obtener un count de la columna de ID_LUGE_MPIO de la tabla RTI_FALLOS. He leido bastante pero no logro solucionarlo, agradezco su colaboración.

```
function f_Consulta_Principal_Casos (P_CODIGO IN 
RTI_MZMPIO.ID_CONSECUTIVO%TYPE)

return sys_refcursor is

v_Consulta sys_refcursor;
begin
open v_Consulta for

SELECT  M.USUARIO_RESPONSABLE,
    L.LUGE_CODIGO AS DEPTO,
    M.ID_LUGE_CODIGO AS MUNICIPIO,  
    M.SOLICITUDES,
    M.SOLICITUDES_RES,
    M.PREDIOS,
    M.(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RTI_FALLOS WHERE ID_LUGE_MPIO=ID_LUGE_CODIGO) 
 FROM RTI_MZMPIO M, LUGARES_GEOGRAFICOS L
 where l.codigo = M.ID_LUGE_CODIGO
 and M.ID_CONSECUTIVO = P_CODIGO;

return(v_Consulta);

exception
when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('Error General f_Consulta_Principal_Casos' || 
Sqlerrm);
  return(null);

end f_Consulta_Principal_Casos;
```

Comment: Ya probaste `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RTI_FALLOS WHERE ID_LUGE_MPIO=M.ID_LUGE_CODIGO`??

Comment: Si ya lo probé y me devuelve efectivamente lo que necesito, pero como necesito que me devuelva ese dato junto con el resto de la consulta, no se como agregarlo